# I want to add name attribute to the apex:inputField

Tags: apexinputfield

I want to add name attribute to the apex:inputField as this input wield will be converted to input when a VF run. So I want to display the field name inside the textbox. I tried with input it works but I need it with apex:inputField so that I can display the proper fields related to the data type. Please help me to get the solution on this issue.

Comment: I remember trying this before and it I was not able to do it, I ended up using the Id's instead.

Comment: Have you tried prepending "html-" in front of the attribute, like **html-name**?

Comment: @MichaelWelburn I've converted your answer to a comment. If you are not sure about an answer or are asking question for more information it's best to use comments.